# One-to-Many relationship with ORMLite

Tags: sql, json, ormlite, ormlite-servicestack

The only examples I can find addressing this sort of scenario are pretty old, and I'm wondering what the best way is to do this with the latest version of ORMLite...

Say I have two tables (simplified):

```
public class Patient
{
   [Alias("PatientId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Insurance
{
   [Alias("InsuranceId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey(typeof("Patient"))]
   public int PatientId { get; set; }
   public string Policy { get; set; }
   public string Level { get; set; }
}
```

Patients can have multiple Insurance policies at different "levels" (primary, secondary, etc). I understand the concept of blobbing the insurance information as a Dictionary type object and adding it directly to the [Patient] POCO like this:

```
public class Patient
{
   public Patient() {
      this.Insurances = new Dictionary<string, Insurance>();  // "string" would be the Level, could be set as an Enum...
   }

   [Alias("PatientId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, Insurance> Insurances { get; set; }
}

public class Insurance
{
   public string Policy { get; set; }
}
```

...but I need the insurance information to exist in the database as a separate table for use in reporting later.

I know I can join those tables in ORMLite, or create a joined View/Stored Proc in SQL to return the data, but it will obviously return multiple rows for the same Patient.

```
SELECT Pat.Name, Ins.Policy, Ins.Level
FROM Patient AS Pat JOIN
   Insurance AS Ins ON Pat.PatientId = Ins.PatientId

(Result)
"Johnny","ABC123","Primary"
"Johnny","987CBA","Secondary"
```

How can I map that into a single JSON response object?

I'd like to be able to map a GET request to "/patients/1234" to return a JSON object like:

```
[{
   "PatientId":"1234",
   "Name":"Johnny",
   "Insurances":[
      {"Policy":"ABC123","Level":"Primary"},
      {"Policy":"987CBA","Level":"Secondary"}
   ]
}]
```

I don't have a lot of hope in this being do-able in a single query. Can it be done in two (one on the Patient table, and a second on the Insurance table)? How would the results of each query be added to the same response object in this nested fashion?

Thanks a ton for any help on this!

## Update - 4/29/14

Here's where I'm at...In the "Patient" POCO, I have added the following:

```
public class Patient
{
   [Alias("PatientId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [Ignore]
   public List<Insurance> Insurances { get; set; }  // ADDED
}
```

Then, when I want to return a patient with multiple Insurances, I do two queries:

```
var patientResult = dbConn.Select<Patient>("PatientId = " + request.PatientId);

List<Insurance> insurances = new List<Insurance>();
var insuranceResults = dbConn.Select<Insurance>("PatientId = " + patientResult[0].PatientId);
foreach (patientInsurance pi in insuranceResults)
{
    insurances.Add(pi);
}

patientResult[0].Insurances = insurances;
patientResult[0].Message = "Success";

return patientResult;
```

This works! I get nice JSON with nested items for Insurances while maintaining separate related tables in the db.

What I don't like is that this object cannot be passed back and forth to the database. That is, I can't use the same nested object to automatically insert/update both the Patient and InsurancePolicy tables at the same time. If I remove the "[Ignore]" decorator, I get a field in the Patient table called "Insurances" of type varchar(max). No good, right?

I guess I'm going to need to write some additional code for my PUT/POST methods to extract the "Insurances" node from the JSON, iterate over it, and use each Insurance object to update the database? I'm just hoping I'm not re-inventing the wheel here or doing a ton more work than is necessary.

Comments would still be appreciated! Is Mythz on? :-) Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate more succinct example:

```
public void Put(CreatePatient request)
{
   var patient = new Patient
   {
      Name = request.Name,
      Insurances = request.Insurances.Map(x => 
          new Insurance { Policy = i.Policy, Level = i.Level })
   };

   db.Save<Patient>(patient, references:true);
}
```

Comment: This is so great! Thank you mythz. Your work and input is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

References are here to save the day!

```
public class Patient
{
   [Alias("PatientId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [Reference]
   public List<Insurance> Insurances { get; set; }
}

public class Insurance
{
   [Alias("InsuranceId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey(typeof("Patient"))]
   public int PatientId { get; set; }
   public string Policy { get; set; }
   public string Level { get; set; }
}
```

I can then take a JSON request with a nested "Insurance" array like this:

```
{
   "Name":"Johnny",
   "Insurances":[
      {"Policy":"ABC123","Level":"Primary"},
      {"Policy":"987CBA","Level":"Secondary"}
   ]
}
```

...to create a new record and save it like this:

```
public bool Put(CreatePatient request)
{
   List<Insurance> insurances = new List<Insurance>();
   foreach (Insurance i in request.Insurances)
   {
      insurances.Add(new Insurance
      {
         Policy = i.Policy,
         Level = i.Level
      });
   }
   var patient = new Patient
   {
      Name = request.Name,
      Insurances = insurances
   };

   db.Save<Patient>(patient, references:true);

   return true;
}
```

Bingo! I get the new Patient record, plus 2 new records in the Insurance table with correct foreign key references back to the PatientId that was just created. This is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

First you should define a foreign collection in Patient class. (with get and set methods)

```
@ForeignCollectionField
private Collection<Insurance> insurances;
```

When you query for a patient, you can get its insurances by calling getInsurances method.

To convert all into a single json object with arrays inside you can use a json processor. I use Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and it works very well. Below will give you json object as a string.

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(patientObject);
```

To correctly map foreign fields you should define jackson references. In your patient class add a managed reference.

```
@ForeignCollectionField
@JsonManagedReference("InsurancePatient")
private Collection<Insurance> insurances;
```

In your insurance class add a back reference.

```
@JsonBackReference("InsurancePatient")
private Patient patient;
```

**Update:**
You can use Jackson to generate objects from json string then iterate and update/create database rows.

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Patient.class);
```

Comment: Interesting...I'm using C#.NET for backend, so Jackson won't work (Java only)? Do you have a suggestion for .NET? I'll look into that ForeignCollectionField...thanks.

Comment: Dang...@ForeignCollectionField looks like just what I need, but I can't figure out how to use it outside of Java? Any pointers?